# cloning a existing object with a new primary key

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 objects as follows

```
class A{
 Set<B>  bs ;

}

class B{
 A a;

}
```

Now, I want to find `A` with id as 1 and insert a new record with id as 2 ,all other values  will be same. Also `B`s associated with `A` should be newly inserted.

For example, if initial `A` with id `1`, and which is associated with 5 `B`s , then after my code executes, I want 2 `A`s with id=1 and 2 and 10 `B`s (5 for A1 and 5 for A2).

I tried following:

```
    stat tx
    A a= Find A with id a 
    make a transient 
    a.setId(null) ;  As id is auto incremnt
    persist A
    commit tx
```

Am getting exception as

> Found two representations of same collection B.

I think it is because `B`s fected has same old id of `A` while inserting

*Note:* I'm using HBM files and not JPA.

Comment: @Akhsay, what is the cascade (of one to many, from A to B )is set to ?

Comment: Also check out this link of transitive persistence (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-transitive). This might help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct it happens because you can't have 2 duplicate objects in the same session.

Please you should detach the object and save it,otherwize please use merge.

You can read more abot merge here:

http://www.hibernate-training-guide.com/merge.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming none of the `B`s' properties need any uniqueness, you should detach all the `B` objects (perhaps those will get detached too, when you detach `A`) and change the value of `A` under each of `B` object -- assign the detached `A`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `BeanUtils.copyProperties(..)` to duplicate the entity. Then set the ID to null, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on this.

1. The identity of an object in JVM is not the same as its identity in Database. Check [**this**](http://tim.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html) link..
2. Even though you changed the primary key, the object reference is still the same. So the Session cache cannot have a reference of an object which it already have (Even though you have changed its id).
3. You will have to create a new object (transient) object to achieve what you are trying to do OR don't let Hibernate manage your identity. Do it yourself. Check the [earlier link](http://tim.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html) mentioned.

Also check out this link of [transitive persistence](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-transitive).  This might help you out.

Comment: He stated that he made the object `transient`.

Comment: @Adeel, to quote Hibernate doc "an object is transient if it has just been instantiated using the new operator, and it is not associated with a Hibernate Session. It has no persistent representation in the database and no identifier value has been assigned". See the link http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html. Akshay does not show code who he 'made and object transient', you can detach a object but not sure how you MAKE it transient.

Comment: By making it `transient`, he meant detaching. And a "detached" object is sufficient here. You can try to print reference of both "managed" and "detached" object, you will see two different references. From the error he posted, it seems, he is having problem with the collection of `B`.